# font-awesome not loading chromium

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm installing font-awesome ("\f0c9") on a web-page and in chromium (debian) is not displaying.

I've checked on Chrome and Safari and its ok.

This font-awesome should appear with small screens.

Code:

```css
.fa-bars:before {
  content: "\f0c9";
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse height navbar-collapse" id="navigation1">
  <button type="button" class="menu-button pull-left"> 
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
 <!-- more code -->
</div>
```

any tips?

Comment: Seems like fontawesome isn't loaded. Normally you don't need to add `.fa-bars:before {
  content: "\f0c9";
}` by yourself. See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99fbbfr9/)

Comment: How did you implement fontawesome iconset?

Comment: Just to confirm, @herrh's fiddle works fine in Chromium v47.0 under Debian.

Comment: i load css from FA (like i said it works with other browsers). The css that i shown its from original FA css, and the html code its from a joomla template that works with others projects that i made before.
Fiddle also works here.